# How to change shape of Material Card (Angular 6)?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

html:

```html
<mat-card class="matcard-black"></mat-card>
```

css:

```css
.matcard-black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(168deg, #000 62%, #000 62%, #000 62%, 
  transparent 63%);

}
```

I want to customize the shape of mat-card. Code which is written 
above just build that shape within the card but I want my card to be 
in that shape.

Comment: What kind of shape are you trying to make?

Comment: @JosephWebber Trapezoidal or triangle

Comment: Check out https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 0):

You can try styling with tag name instead of class name (i.e. `mat-card`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
mat-card {
      background-color: black;
      height: 400px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      background: linear-gradient(168deg, #000 62%, #000 62%, #000 62%, 
      transparent 63%);
}
```